# Python Pandas: Using an array to choose different columns for each value of a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe and I want a new column with the highest magnitude value from a set of other columns (i.e. the most positive or most negative, -4 would be picked over 2). I can use .abs().idxmax to find the column with the largest absolute value:

```
df[["col A","col B"]].abs().idxmax(axis=1)
```

This gives me a nice array, castable to a list if desired, of ["col A", "col B"..] and so on showing which column has the maximum magnitude, but how do I use that to construct a new column from the values in the indicated locations?

This doesn't work:

```
df["newcol"] = df[df[["col A","col B"]].abs().idxmax(axis=1)]
```

Even if I put a .loc in there or use the values or a list of the values from the previous output. Is there a pandas native (non-loop) way to build a new column with values of each row picked by a list of column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `idxmax`, it would be easier (and faster) to use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
condition = df['col A'].abs() >= df['col B'].abs()
df['new col'] = np.where(condition, df['col A'], df['col B'])
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2015)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,2))-5, columns=['col A', 'col B'])
condition = df['col A'].abs() >= df['col B'].abs()
df['new col'] = np.where(condition, df['col A'], df['col B'])
```

yields

```
   col A  col B  new col
0     -3     -3       -3
1      4      1        4
2      3      0        3
3      2      3        3
4     -5      1       -5
5      2      3        3
6     -2      3        3
7      1      4        4
8     -3     -2       -3
9     -4     -3       -4
```

---

If starting from `idx = df[["col A","col B"]].abs().idxmax(axis=1)` 
is a requirement, then you could select the desired values
by creating a MultiIndex from `idx.index` and `idx.values`, and then selecting the values using `df.stack().loc[idx]`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2015)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,2))-5, columns=['col A', 'col B'])

idx = df[["col A","col B"]].abs().idxmax(axis=1)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([idx.index, idx.values])
df['new_col'] = df.stack().loc[idx].values
```

yields the same result as above.

Comment: I like the ".where" approach (it's FAST!), is there a good way to scale that to more than 2 columns? My "col A", "col B" was a simplified example. I can see how to use a chain of such comparisons though, so I'll mark this as the accepted answer if nobody comes up with better (which would surprise me) soon. The multiindex probably wouldn't work *for me* as I already have a big multiindex in the real application, but another neat idea and example of manipulation there.

Comment: @EzekielKruglick: [`np.select`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) may be what you are looking for. It is a `n`-conditional generalization of `np.where`.

Comment: aha, very nice spot on np.select, n-conditional boolean input! Always excellent advice from unutbu.